# Counting the number of occurences for each element

Tags: python, list

I have two lists, similar to these

```
listA = ['apples','apples','oranges','pears','pears','watermelons','..']
listB = ['apples','oranges','pears','watermenols','...']
```

So the listA has just a list of fruits, where potential duplicates are in a row. The listB has each fruit, but only once and in the same order as listA.

Is it possible to count (and print) the number of each fruit, for example like this
apples 2
orange 1
pears 1
etc

I think you could do it with two loops, but I'm not quite sure how the loops should be...

edit: This should be done WITHOUT any fancy imports and stuff, so just the basics like loops and lists

thanks! :)

Comment: Use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count them.

Comment: Why do you need list B? Do you need only to count elements in listA?

Comment: If you don't want to use a Counter, you can do `{x:listA.count(x) for x in listB}`

Comment: Do I understand correctly that only items that are in `listB` should be counted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Pythonic Way to Count Objects is to use Python’s Counter from collections

```
from collections import Counter

listA = ['apples','apples','oranges','pears','pears','watermelons',]
res = dict(Counter(listA))
print (res)

# {'apples': 2, 'oranges': 1, 'pears': 2, 'watermelons': 1}
```

basic way:

```
listA = ['apples','apples','oranges','pears','pears','watermelons',]
result = {}

for fruit in listA:
   if fruit in result:
       result[fruit] += 1
   else:
       result[fruit] = 1

print(result)
# {'apples': 2, 'oranges': 1, 'pears': 2, 'watermelons': 1}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without a counter? I have read around and many people have told that counter is one way, but we are not supposed to use it yet (This problem is part of a course i am taking in high school and we have not been taught the usage of counter yet)

Comment: @PythoNoob I edit my post

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me perfectly! :)

Comment: @PythoNoob Youre welcome, I am glad that I helped